# Raw roast beef on the edge of safe?

Tags: food-safety

I'm disabled and have a person help with groceries and meals. Today, she bought roast beef at the grocery store and immediately put together a beef stew for me (no time in fridge at home), but she didn't notice the crockpot was unplugged. I discovered it about 3 1/2 hours later and plugged it in. Should I let the stew finish cooking or throw it out? Keep in mind if I throw it out, I won't have dinner for the next 3 days and will be living on cereal and Halloween candy. Not an exaggeration.

Comment: Think about it the other way. If you get deathly sick from the beef stew that have been in the danger zone way longer than safe, what will you do with no one to take care of you for 3 days? I don't know exactly how you are disabled but from the fact that you won't be able to go and get more food, I'd say dealing with a stomach flu with your disability will be very difficult. Maybe cereal and candy isn't the healthiest but at least you know you won't get sick from it.

Comment: We can't tell you what you should do, there isn't an answer to that. It's a matter of a personal decision. We can only tell you when it's safe, but it seems that you already know it.